# Является ли usb-кабель зарядным устройством?

Tags: названия

Является ли usb-кабель компонентом (или лучше сказать элементом?) зарядного устройства или в целом (или лучше сказать сам по себе?) зарядным устройством?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Технически это ни само зарядное устройство, ни элемент такого устройства, а просто **соединительный кабель** с двумя разъемами USB разного типоразмера. Можно навать его **принадлежностью** зарядного устройства, если кабель вместе с ним продаётся или постоянно к нему подключён одним концом (без разъёма). В частном случае кабелем USB можно подключить к компьютеру (или к специализированному источнику питания, напр. подключаемому к сети) некоторые устройства (фотокамера, телефон и др.) аккумулятор которых требуется зарядить. Такие устройства внутренне преобразуют *напряжение линии питания USB* (5 Вольт, по двум из 4 проводов такого кабеля) в *ток заряда* своего аккумулятора. Вторая пара проводов кабеля USB - информационная, при зарядке не используется.

Answer (score -1):

Это **зарядное устройство от USB-порта**.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зарядное_устройство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Или USB зарядное устройство. В народе - USB зарядка.

Comment: Ох уж эти гуманитарии. Каким это образом четыре простых проводка в одной оплетке превратились в зарядное устройство? Это просто USB кабель. При заряде от USB порта компьютера зарядным устройством является блок питания компьютера, который предоставляет стабилизированное напряжения 5В для USB портов.

Comment: Зарядное устройство - это то, чем можно зарядить. Разницы нет - от сети или от USB порта, или от трансформатора. В данном случае - зарядное от порта USB. В комплекте с [этим переходником](https://www.stall.com.ua/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/x111.jpg54352e5d17b2e.jpg.pagespeed.ic.mgj-2PHJ7o.jpg) уже ни у кого не останется сомнений, что это зарядное устройство, так как разницы в результате работы нет. То есть, если вам нужно будет зарядить телефон у кого-то в гостях, вы скажете "дай-ка мне свой USB кабель"? Так не говорят.

Comment: Этак вы и сетевой провод назовете электростанцией. Какая ведь разница что он куда-то втыкается, главное, что в нём электричество есть, так ведь?

Comment: Нет. Электростанция вырабатывает электричество, и в больших масштабах. || Такой ответ - это не моё мнение, а информация с Википедии. В таком случае нужно обязательно уточнять, что зарядное устройство именно от порта USB.

Comment: Так и USB порт, в вашей терминологии, "вырабатывает электричество". А USB кабель его просто доставляет до потребителя, как и сетевой шнур. Вы если уж ссылаетесь на статью в википедии, так хотя бы сами её почитайте. Где вы там увидели, что USB кабель является "зарядкой"?? там кабели вообще ни словом не упоминаются. Знаете, у вас обычно хорошие обоснованные ответы, но вот этот ваш ответ, это просто вопиющая глупость. Вы бы лучше его удалили, что ли - техника, это явно не ваше. Извините за прямоту.

Comment: Стоп. Да вы всё перекручиваете. В USB порте **стабилизируется** напряжение специальным контроллером, но никак не вырабатывается. Мы же не называем устройства, которые стабилизируют напряжение 220 В в розетке, элементом зарядного устройства, а просто говорим, что зарядное работает от сети - обыкновенная зарядка. А это иная - от порта USB. Да и не стоит судить про технику лишь по одному ответу. || Исходил из этого: https://i.imgur.com/w6Ybmh1.png

Comment: И как картинка фонарика подтверждает, что USB кабель является зарядным устройством? Ладно, лучше на этом закончить, я уже чувствую, что начинаю с вами с ума сходить. Всё, я сдаюсь. Пусть будет по-вашему, считайте как хотите.

Comment: Не картинка, а то, что под ней написано. Если логически подумать, то это любое, чем можно зарядить. А от чего заряжать - это уже второстепенный момент. Словосочетание "USB зарядка" уже стало общеупотребительным. Возможно, что это условно, так как первостепенной остаётся функция передачи информации.